# How to pass variables from links in PHP?

Tags: php, database, mysqli, download

I crated a page indes.php with the following code :

```
    <?php

include "db.php";

$select="SELECT *FROM alldocs ";

$query=mysqli_query($conn,$select);

<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">



 <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name"><br><br>

 <input type="file" name="file" ><br><br>

 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"><br><br>



</form>

<div class="box-info">

    <?php

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

            echo $row['name'].'<br>'.

            '<a href="downloud.php?get=$path">downloud file</a>    <br>';}

    ?>

</div>
```

then I created the upload.php like this

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){



include "db.php";

$name   =$_POST['name'];

$file   =$_FILES['file'];

$fileName   =$file['name'];

$fileTmp    =$file['tmp_name'];

$path='downloud/$fileName';

if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmp , $path)){

    $insert=" INSERT INTO alldocs(name,path) VALUES('$name','$path')";

    $query=mysqli_query($conn,$insert);

    header("Location:index.php");

}}

?>
```

Now I the index.pho in the link I tried to hook up at the get=$path so that I can get in the next page which will make it possible to download the path from the db like this :

```
<?php 

if(isset($_GET['get'])){ 



    include "db.php";

    $path=$_GET['get'];



    $select="SELECT*FROM alldocs WHERE path='$path';" ;

    $query=mysqli_query($conn,$select);



    header('Conetent-type:application/octet-stream');

    header('Conetent-disposition:attachment;filename="'.basename($path).'"' );

    header('Conetent-lenght:.filesize($path)'); 

    readfile($path);

}

?>
```

So please if someone could point out to me the error that I have made in this code because I always get this error `WARNING: readfile($path); as undefined`!

Comment: There are typos in this `header('Conetent-lenght:` - did you type that yourself from a video tutorial or a book?

Comment: yes i did , honestly . Im not familiar with php ! I can manage to upload files in DB but not download and im learning it step by step

Comment: All of those `Conetent` header prefixes should be `Content`. Your SQL query has a SQL injection vulnerability, so don't put this live yet.

Comment: No halfer  , i didn't secure .I just was curious how the architecture of the download code works , I'm pretty new the PHP i i still keep learning step by step .I know sometimes  i ask stupid question ! But I hope someone understands that ! thank you for the attention halfer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of my code was that i didn't pass the path right , so for the :

```
<?php
```

include "db.php";

$id=$_GET['id'];

$query="SELECT*FROM test WHERE id='$id' ";

$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

```
$path = $row['path'];   <--  //*getting the path *//-->

header('Content-Disposition:attachment; filename ='.$path.'');    <--// obviously i 
                                                               don't know if the 
                                                               basename is needed 
                                                               here *//-->
header('Content-type:application/octent-strem'); 
header('Content-lenght='.filesize($path)); 

readfile($path);
```

}

this code works for downloading files/images!

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to pass the path

```
header("Location:index.php");
```

Should be

```
header("Location:index.php?get=".urlencode($path));
```

Comment: the path header to upload .php

Comment: yes Forbs you are right i forgot the pass the path thank You so much for the help !

Comment: @burimrexhepi well if it helped mark it answered please